# in wordpress i want to send the user his password by mail?

Tags: wordpress, passwords, password-storage

i have a workflow in which a user when gets approved by system. Gets his login credentials as username and password. I want to send the user when he is approved his username and password in a mail. I am not sure how can i retrieve a user password from database is there an already existing function in wordpress?

Comment: should never send a password by email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store this with user_meta functions ( http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta | http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta | http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/delete_user_meta | http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta ). So when user registers you save his password with something like add_user_meta($uid, "clearPass", $val) and then get it back when you're sending those emails..

But as said before, it isn't the best approach at all.

Comment: Yes i understand. But thanks for exposing the user_meta functions

Answer (score 3):

Wordpress doesn't store clear-text passwords. If you can, you'll have to generate a (new) password, update the wordpress database with the crypt hash (using `wp_hash_password($clear_text_password)`) and send the cleartext password by email after that DB update succeeds.

Comment: Intially i present a registeration form to the user. Where they enter username password and other credentials. Then when they submit the administrator gets a mail where he checks users details. After that he has to allow users to login. But i think by that time users may forget there password so how can i retrieve the password they entered and send it back to them

Comment: Its a _very_ bad idea to store clear-text passwords even if only until approval, if you're worried about people forgetting passwords, its better to provide a mechanism to reset it. I'm sure WP already has that mechanism.

Comment: As @skjaidev says, you can't - since the WordPress password hashing is a true hash - i.e. it's one direction only, you cannot retrieve the password from the database.  You have to generate a new one, store it in the db, and send the user that. That's how the WordPress password recovery system works, and it's the right way to store passwords.

Comment: Can i ask user to register initially without a password. See his information that he has entered verify his information and send him the username and randomly generated password...

Comment: That is definitely possible, you'll need to tweak WP though.

Comment: @skjaidev how can i modify the Registeration page to do so